# PyroCMS is not showing some of the images on pages

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, pyrocms

Pyrocms stopped showing image after restoring the backup on the server.

now some images are not displaying and when you copy paste URL of the image in browser to check if images are there then it gives following message in browser rather than image or 404 error.

`The Image "https://www.xxxx.com/files/large/slide1.jpg" cannot be displayed because it contains errors`

This is happening with most of the images but some image are showing.

When i use firebug to inspect it i can see following

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height;">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="resource://content-accessible/ImageDocument.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="resource://content-accessible/TopLevelImageDocument.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://global/skin/media/TopLevelImageDocument.css">
      <title>slide1.jpg (JPEG Image)</title>
   </head>
   <body cz-shortcut-listen="true"><img src="https://www.xxxx.com/files/large/slide1.jpg" alt="The image “https://www.xxxx.com/files/large/slide1.jpg” cannot be displayed because it contains errors."></body>
</html>
```

Not sure why this is happening as vendor is pointing to server configuration while it is the same server on which website was working but after restoring the whole website from backup some images stopped showing.

Comment: Try downloading `slide1.jpg` via ftp (not browser). If you still can't view it chances are the images are irreparably corrupted and you should attempt to manually restore them or restore from a non-corrupted backup (first verify the contents).

Comment: Sounds like corrupted files. Would be curious as to the MD5s.

Comment: This issue was resolved by installing pyro cms on new instance